# In Javascript, is there any way to access a variable that is defined within a function from outside of it?

Tags: javascript, function

If I have a function:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = "variable defined inside of myFunction";   
}
```

Is there any trick I can use to access x from outside of it?

I read about variables being scoped but was just wondering if there was any way around it.

Comment: Yes, `return` it

Comment: Also note that if your function involves launching an asynchronous operation, you've got other problems